# storyboard disabled my view

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uistoryboard

For some reason my storyboard disabled my view. I can move all elements to can not see them.

any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have changed the size class. The "greyed out" views in the navigator are greyed out because they are defined under a different size class.

Change to Any-Any and it will prob come back. If not try the other size classes.

Comment: dosn't work  with me.  Can i share my desk with you? Many thanks @Fogmeister

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a mask exclusion defined in Storyboard file:

```
<variation key="default">
    <mask key="subviews">
        <exclude reference="QjJ-Nd-P4H"/>
    </mask>
</variation>
```

Open the storyboard file as source code (Right-Click on storyboard file, Open As... -> Source Code) and search for any exclusions. Remove those in XML and open the storyboard again in Interface Builder.